# Java ".class expected"

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lottery
{
    private int[] lotteryNumbers = new int[5];
    private int counter;
    private int[] userNumbers = new int[5];
    private Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);  
    public Lottery()
    {
        for(counter = 0; counter < 5; counter++)
        {
            lotteryNumbers[counter] = nextInt(int 10);
        }
    }
```

There is more code after, but there are no errors there, so I'm not gonna include it.
Anyway, the line that says "lotteryNumbers[counter] = nextInt(int 10);" get a ".class expected" error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Java already knows the type of the method parameter; you don't need to specify it when you call the method.

```
nextInt(int 10);
```

Should be:

```
nextInt(10);
```

This is assuming, of course, that you actually have a method `nextInt` defined.  (I don't see it in your code sample)

Answer (score 2):

What's the `int` for?

If you're trying to cast, it should be `(int)`.

The reason you're getting that error is that when Java sees a type name where an expression is expected, it thinks you're trying to refer to that type's class object, e.g. `int.class`.

Answer (score 2):

Java's an object-oriented language.  What object are you invoking `nextInt(10)` on?  I don't see one.  The compiler will assume this implicitly.  Does your `Lottery` use a `Random` instance somewhere?  I don't see it.

I think you need something like this:

```
private Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Then your loop should do this:

```
lotteryNumbers[counter] = this.random.nextInt(10);
```

I have other issues with what you're doing:

- Unnecessary "magic" numbers everywhere.  It's possible to make this class far more flexible than what you've got.
- Mixing input into classes like this is a bad idea.  Make an abstraction that you can pass values into and leave where you get them from alone.  Think "single responsibility".
- I don't see why `Lottery` needs a private data member for user numbers.  However, I can see where it might have a method that would accept user numbers and tell whether they won or not.  You've created a poor abstraction, in my opinion.

This might get you going for a while.

Comment: That would be the problem. The book my prof made us get tells us the random methods but skipped the part that you needed to create a random object

Comment: Kind of hard not to blame the prof. He made us buy a book, said read it and do the assignments. So IMO it's his fault for not being a real prof. I could have done that shit at home without paying.

Comment: As far as the edit in your post goes, I'm doing the assignment exactly as the book tells me to. I have prior programming experience in C++, and that prof stressed good programming style. This one is an idiot and I have to deal with what he wants or fail.

Comment: It's required for the degree. It has a lot of impact, but when there are specific instructions that need to be followed, I follow them. Even if it makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the specifics of nextInt(), I'd suggest the error would be from the 'int' keyword before the parameter you're passing to it. Try:

```
lotteryNumbers[counter] = nextInt(10);
```